# JavaFX 21 Mouse Scroll Wheel Only Moving In One Direction on Linux Mint 21

Tags: java, javafx, java-21

I have a Java 8 JavaFX app that works fine on Ubuntu and Linux Mint 21. However on migrating to Java 21 and JavaFX 21 I've found that the mouse scroll wheel only works in one direction.

I found a comment in another forum post that others have seen this issue and is related to Java and gtk:

https://support.motivewave.com/forum/index.php?threads/motivewave-and-linux-performance-improvements.765/

I also found this OpenJDK post that support for GTK version 2 has now been dropped from JavaFX as of December 2020:

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8277962

I actually tried adding the runtime option -Djdk.gtk.version=2 but get the warning:

WARNING: A command line option tried to seleet the GTK 2 library, which was remove from JavaFX. The GTK 3 library will be used instead.

OK - But how do I get back the correct behaviour of the mouse scroll wheel with Java/JavaFX 21 on Linux?

Comment: I’m not able to reproduce this.  I just wrote a small application using Java 21 and JavaFX 21, and the mouse wheel works just fine in Debian/Gnome.

Comment: [GTK 2 support in JavaFX was deprecated for removal in JavaFX 18](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8277962) (just references the same issue report you mention in your question).  Try your code with the `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` option on JRE 17 and JavaFX 17 and see if it works.  It may not be the version you want to use, but it might at least help you narrow down your issue.  Also, if GTK3 is not installed on your system, you could try upgrading your OS to use GTK3.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a [mcve] that replicates the issue.  That way if somebody wants and is able, they could copy the exact code from your question that exhibits issues on your platform and try to replicate your issue.

Comment: gtk2 was dropped in Linux and now gtk3. JavaFX officially stopped support for gtk2 in Dec 2020, and now issue a warning [copied&pasted in my original post] if an attempt is made to call it. Thus, the "-Djdk.gtk.version=2" is not an option, as outlined in my original post. gtk3 is installed on Linux Mint 21 and so no need to upgrade the OS. Regarding "replicates the issue", this is not always possible when dealing with a 20 year old application! I have found that by "export"-ing "GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1" it solves the issue but this is far from an ideal solution.

Comment: It may work as you expect if you use "Try your code with the -Djdk.gtk.version=2 option on JRE 17 and JavaFX 17." *and* ensure that [GTK 2 is installed in your distribution](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213081).  I think Linux can function with both GTK2 and 3 installed.  I didn't try it, so it may not work.  It may not be a solution that works for your case anyway and your workaround with `GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS` export seems better as well.  So the setup I described in this comment is probably not worth trying, just offering an alternate potential solution.

Comment: Eventually, Java SE and JavaFX will likely be upgraded to function with GTK4, and versions of the software that support that would likely be better to use for your purposes, but, unfortunately, neither Java SE nor JavaFX currently supports GTK4 at version 21 of those platforms.

Comment: jewels -thanks, but I think you need to read my posts in that I'm using JavaFX and the official warning that is now issued: "WARNING: A command line option tried to seleet the GTK 2 library, which was remove from JavaFX. The GTK 3 library will be used instead.". Even if GTK2 was on the system (which isn't any longer by default) then JavaFX will not use it. You suggest using J17 - my posts states J21. Thus, such comments are just time wasting. "Eventually...GTK4..." - how's that help today?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer because this system doesn't allow me to add the link as a comment.

A link to others experiencing the mouse scroll wheel issue and use of the flag GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1:

[https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/gtk-3-mouse-wheel-doesn't-work-on-current-wed-sep-25-a-4175478706/](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/gtk-3-mouse-wheel-doesn%27t-work-on-current-wed-sep-25-a-4175478706/)

Comment: The comment syntax is basic markdown syntax, you should be able to [post links in comments](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links).  That said, this is probably best as an answer anyway.